# c: wordexp for variable passed in

Tags: c++, c, parsing, arguments

I can't seem to get this to work. `wordexp()` works awesomely when I call it like:

```
wordexp("beep", &p, 0);
w = p.we_wordv;
argc = p.we_wordc;
```

However I want to pass in some values the user will enter and then get the `argv` and `argc` from that. Right now I have the following code, but I always receive a "Segmentation Fault" or "EXC_BAD_ACCESS":

```
char **parseCommand(char *args, int *argc) {
    printf("args %s\n", args);
    wordexp_t p;
    char **w;
    int i;
    char *beep;

    wordexp(args, &p, 0);

    w = p.we_wordv;
    argc = p.we_wordc;

    wordfree(&p);
    return w;
}
```

When I print the args, it shows it. I have even tried `strcpy` the args to another string. But still getting the error. Must be something silly (or can't do this with wordexp)?

Comment: You presumably use `*argc = p.we_wordc;`?  Otherwise, your compiler should be complaining to you.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your problem is

> The  function  wordfree()  frees the allocated memory again.  More precisely, it does not free its argument, but it frees the array  we_wordv and the strings that points to.

so you return a pointer to `free`d memory, when you access that, a segmentation fault is not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view if you assign p.we_wordv to 'w' and after that you destroy 'p' object/struct the whole content(fields inside - we_wordv) is also destroyed means 'w' point to some random data, and its depends on compiler, or current runetime situation if they are still valid or not.

You should use malloc to assign memory to p and after that copy the content and return the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access argv[] and argc directly from main(). From there you can pass them on to other functions.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char ** parsed = parseCommand(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. However, it looks like the error was because it was passing in a string with a newline and it did not like that. Seems to be working now after I remove the newline from the string.